How to trigger a job in Jenkins from teams, just like slack
I want to trigger my Jenkisn job from teams, just like slack.
where I can provide command like build or abort like that to trigger or to stop job.
I tried with connector but it only provide status of my builds.
also checked How to trigger Jenkin Jobs from Microsoft Team Channel?
but not understanding how to implement this with outgoing webhook

The outgoing webhook is your best option. This video by Microsoft shows how to create the webhook in detail. In the video, the presenter:

Creates an API server with an API endpoint
Creates an outgoing webhook that is pointed to the API server he created
Calls the API endpoint via webhook by using @mention in a teams channel

In your case, you don't have to create an API server or endpoint because the endpoint to trigger a job is provided by Jenkins (basically, you can skip the stuff where he creates the server and uses ngrok to expose it). Read up on the Remote access API to get an idea of how you can start Jenkins jobs by calling API endpoints. Then use the endpoint for the outgoing webhook. You can essentially start the video from 8:33 and use the Jenkins endpoint as the callback URL.

curl -X POST -u BuildUser:***** "http://...:8080/job/terraform-asset-work/buildWithParameters?token=TokenName&AutoApprove=yes"
When I ran this its was trigger my build.
But how can I add this in form of callback URL of my teams channel during webhook creation.

@M B
can you please provide me some solution or your thoughts here? any refernece.

@Swara If I remember correctly, you should be able to include the username and pass in the url itself `http://BuildUser:password@...:8080/job/terraform-asset-work/buildWithParameters?AutoApprove=yes. You could set this URL as the callback.

@M B
URL I formed : http://BuildUser:@...:8080/job/terraform-assets-work/buildWithParameters?token=authToken&autoApprove=yes
after adding this in webhook how can i test this integration via triggering job

If it works properly you should be able to trigger the jenkins job by sending a teams message, similar to how they have done it in the tutorial.

Where to use that outgoing webhook in job ? @M B

hey @M B please provide a suggestions
